# Fastest way to traverse or find elements in DIV HTML

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsoup, jtidy

I am writing an utility which should hit the URL of a dynamic page, retrieve the content, search for a specific div tag in various nested div tags and grab the content.

Mainly, I am looking for some Java code/library. JavaScript or some JavaScript-based library would also work for me.

I shortlisted following -> JSoup, Jerry, JTidy(last updated in 2009-12-01). Which one is best performance wise?

**Edit**: Rephrased the question. Added shortlisted lib.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to scrape a page and parse it I recommend using node with jsdom.

install nodeJS (assuming linux):

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd ~
git clone git://github.com/joyent/node
cd node
git checkout v0.6
mkdir ~/.local # If it doesn't already exist
./configure --prefix=~/.local
make
make install
```

There is also a windows installer: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.6/node-v0.6.6.msi

install jsdom:

```
$ npm install jsdom
```

Run this script modified with your url and the relevant selectors:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

jsdom.env({
    html: 'url',
    done: function(errors, window) {
        console.log(window.document.getElementById('foo').textContent;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like jQuery's simple syntax, you can try [Jerry](http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/) :

```
Jerry is a jQuery in Java. Jerry is a fast and concise Java Library that simplifies HTML document parsing, traversing and manipulating.
Jerry is designed to change the way that you parse HTML content.
```

Syntax seems to be very simple.
It should solve your problem in maximum 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/

JTidy is pretty good at parsing the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're after is a selector engine, then [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) is your best bet. Its the engine used by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

give the unique id for each div and get by using document.getElementById(id)